# Get available CIDRs from existing VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm writing a few templates to create a stack on demand.
Because of the concurrent VPC limitations (5 to start), I'm attempting to create all the feature-based dev environments on a single VPC and mostly divide the stacks by subnets. The idea is that every stack will have 2 private and 2 public subnets.
I know I can get specific CIDRs with something like this (YAML):

```
!Select [ 0, !Cidr [ !GetAtt MyVpc.CidrBlock, 1, 8 ]]
```

But I need to make sure I'm getting CIDRs that are not being used by some of the other stack.
Programmatically, I would get all CIDR blocks from the VPC and then filter all the ones that are used by other subnets, to get a final array (or simply return x items from the array).

**Is getting a block of free CIDRs or a single free one something I can do with the intrinsic functions?**

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about putting each stack in its own set of subnets, that's an overkill.

Simply make the resources' **Security Groups** refer to other *SGs* in your stack templates and not to subnet CIDRs.

What that means is for example the RDS SG sg-123456 will permit traffic from App SG sg-9876543 and not from the App subnet 10.20.30.0/24 you'll be fine from the network isolation perspective.

We usually have the VPC infrastructure shared for dev, test and feature stacks. That's perfectly fine. Moreover we also use **[CloudFormation Exports](https://aws.nz/best-practice/cloudformation-exports/)** to simplify the templates.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It is an interesting approach. I'll see if this is a good alternative for our scenario.

Comment: Loved the blog post too. I'll be adding that as well.